# Field name `username` is not valid for model `User` django rest-auth

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use Django rest_auth login with email :

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from users.models import User
from rest_auth.serializers import LoginSerializer




class CustomLoginSerializer(LoginSerializer):
  username = None
  email = serializers.EmailField(required = True)
  password1 = serializers.CharField(write_only = True)

  class Meta:
     model = User
     fields = ('email','password')
```

imported the loginview:

```
from rest_auth.views import LoginView

class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
queryset = User.objects.all()
```

user model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from rest_framework.authtoken.models  import Token


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('user must have email address')
    now = timezone.now()
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(
        email=email,
        is_staff=is_staff,
        is_active=True,
        is_superuser=is_superuser,
        last_login=now,
        date_joined=now,
        **extra_fields
    )
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    return self._create_user(email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    user=self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
     email = models.EmailField(max_length = 100, unique = True)
     First_Name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True, blank = True)
     Last_Name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True, blank = True)
     is_staff = models.BooleanField(default = False)
     is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default = False)
     is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
     last_login = models.DateTimeField(null = True, blank = True)
     date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

     USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
     EMAIL_FIELD = "email"
     REQUIRED_FIELD = []

     objects = UserManager()

     def get_absolute_url(self):
         return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)
```

settings.py:

```
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
'LOGIN_SERIALIZER': 'api.serializers.CustomLoginSerializer'
```

}

I have created a custom user modal with email so as the error shows the username is valid but how can I remove it from login. when I run the localhost:8000/rest-auth/login I am getting email and password view but after login, it showing this:

```
  Field name `username` is not valid for model `User`
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add username to the serializer, just remove the `username = None`

Comment: also you need to write in the fields ('email', 'password1')

Comment: when i does not add username its automatically add that

Comment: Its probrably using the default user model. You can probrably just rename the model 'user' and it would work normal.

Comment: i tried that importing user as customuser but username field still showing

Comment: You need to change the model itself, change the model to CustomerUser and then import it like from models import CustomerUser

Comment: Dont forget that you will need to delete the table and migrate and makemigrations, so be careful

Comment: Also you need to probably add this to settings if you didn't already: AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomerUser'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199285/discussion-between-afk-and-liudvikas-bajarunas).